# Trying to save a customer using Stripe.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a customer and associate a token id with it using stripe.js. Till now I have created a stripe token using the following code:

```
 Stripe.card.createToken({
                number: $('#cc-number').val(),
                cvc: $('#cc-cvc').val(),
                exp_month: $('#cc-exp').val().substr(0, 2),
                exp_year: $('#cc-exp').val().substr(3, 2),
                name: $('#cc-name').val()
            }, stripeResponseHandler);
```

Once I get the response from stripe, I want to store the credit card and associate it with a customer. Maybe use something like this:

```
stripeResponseHandler = function (status, response) {
    Stripe.customers.create({
                    description: 'Testing',
                    source: response.id 
                });
}
```

But this is not working, I keep getting the error "Uncaught typeError: undefined "create" . What am I missing here? Any help appreciated.

Comment: `create` is undefined. Is `stripe` supposed to be capitalized like it is in your first code block?

Comment: Oh I did capitalize it and try got the same error.

Comment: What about the missing `)` when you call `create`? Does that have any effect on the error message?

Comment: I'm Sorry, Titus. I made some typos while posting the question. Just fixed them.

Comment: No problem. It would be a strange error wording if this was the case, but what happens if you add the callback to `create` like in the documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_customer

Comment: I followed this document, added the requireJs to my Asp.Net application. I was still stuck with same error and it never reached the callback function